# How to flush the input buffer of a SerialDevice

Tags: serial-port, buffer, uwp, flush

I'm creating a UWP application that needs to read data from a USB input device via the virtual serial port that it exposes.

I have used [this tutorial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/serialsample) to achieve a working prototype using the `SerialCommunication.SerialDevice` class. However, I need to flush the input stream when the serial port is first opened, to discard any unwanted data that may be in the buffer of the input device before the application connects to it.

The obvious solution seems to be to keep reading the port until there is nothing left to read; something like this:

```
uint bytes;

do
{
    bytes = await _dataReader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength);
    _dataReader.ReadString(bytes);
} while (bytes > 0);
```

However, this doesn't work because `LoadAsync()` waits indefinitely if there is no data to read.

Is there a way to query the contents of the input stream before attempting to read it, or alternatively to unconditionally flush it?

Thanks for your suggestions,

Tim

UPDATE: In response to comments from @Hans Passant, I modified the code as follows to detect content in the input buffer before attempting to read it:

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
Debug.WriteLine("BytesReceived: {0}", _serialDevice.BytesReceived); // 0 bytes
var bytesRead = await _dataReader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength);
Debug.WriteLine("BytesRead: {0}", bytesRead); // 75 bytes
```

So, despite waiting 1000ms (to allow the device adequate time to send what is in its buffer), `BytesReceived` fails to detect any data, but `LoadAsync` reads 75 bytes immediately afterwards.

Comment: Use the SerialDevice.BytesReceived property to know how many bytes you can read without blocking.

Comment: @Hans thanks - great suggestion - but that doesn't seem to work. If I read  SerialDevice.BytesReceived it always returns zero, even though an immediate follow-on call to _dataReader.LoadAsync returns a positive value.

Comment: It is not crystal to me why you try to purge at all when BytesReceived is 0.  The most logical explanation is that the device immediately sends something when it sees the handshake signals turn on.  But that takes time, at least a millisecond at 9600 baud.  If you want to get rid of those as well then you have to Task.Delay() for 100 msec, give or take.

Comment: @Hans: Yes, I was thinking along exactly the same lines, so I tested a delay before posting my last comment. I have updated my question to show exactly what I tested and the results it produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataReader.LoadAsync() won't return until one or more bytes are received. In case your input buffer is empty, it'll block your code.

You can use the CancellationToken to cancel the read task in order to "flush" the serial input buffer.

Below is the code that does the trick.

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)))
{
     await dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(1024).AsTask(cts.Token);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a smart solution to the problem.